How to determine a workflow from example images
An internet mystery has people searching for an unknown person on a fabric.
I try to understand the following:

What workflow did the designer use to transform the images?
Can we tell from the before and after images if the designer used the same process for all photos, or even different designers might have been involved?
Can this workflow be replicated to achieve similar results (excluding cleanup) for comparison with suspected source images of the unknown person?
Were there any well-known workflows in Illustrator, Photoshop, or other tools used for this effect? (around 2008)


I believe understanding the fabric designer's workflow might help identify this person.
Here is what I tried:
I experimented with GIMP's "color -> threshold" function. I can achieve partial results for specific areas, like reproducing the lost eyelid folds and half the upper lip in the first image (Adriana Lima). However, other features are significantly affected, like a missing nose and overly darkened neck.
Thank you for your support!
Six other celebrities and (likely) source images have been identified:







Credit for the info and images:
https://lostmediawiki.com/Celebrity_Number_Six_(lost_original_photo_of_unidentified_celebrity;_date_unknown)

@oneprivate thanks, but difficult to understand for me. But I'll install Krita and try it out

don't expect a workflow that creates the result automatically. threshold on a greyscale image, in combination with blur will give you some result, but that has to be refined by manual retouching. for example if you look at the shiny, zigzaggy parts of the hair, that is always painted in afterwards. Also the eye details.

Some of the found images won't fit exactly on top of the graphics. Like Jessica Alba who has her head turned slightly different. So either it's not the right images or the process involved some amount of manual drawing. Perhaps the images were traced by hand and vectorized afterwards. I don't think it's just a filter.

@wolff you are right, some of the photos might not be the exact photos. Some also think they might be skewed .Also sorry but I didn't mean to restrict by Gimp only.

Main process.. copyright infringement :).. These were most likely hand traced. Or Posterized, then auto-traced (which would account for some discrepancies.) Or a mix of the two. Some areas would somewhat have to be manually created due to the "similar surrounding tones" and minute details- like hair, facial and other wise.

@Scott haha yeah, I wouldn't be surprised if they didn't even get permission to use those photos. That's why they used old ones (for the time) or from some random event.

Kinda starting to seem more like a social media meme than a design question... The dress is blue and black damn it!

@Scott sorry I am not sure I understand? I am actually interested how to generate a workflow that can reproduce the design here. So that I can apply it to images I think could be that person. Plus learning about the other questions might help to get an idea what to look for.

Then remove all the irrelevant social media/reddit stuff. How is any of that pertinent.. or the "search for the sixth".  Sorry.. just feels a lot like click bait to me. I can be wrong.. happens all the time :)

I can remove any information that isn't wanted on this stack. I thought someone might be interested. And I also thought the background for my question explains more the reason for it.
I understand that it might not be the typical question here. Especially as I'm not a professional or much interested in graphic design otherwise.
I suppose usually the question would be more like, how do I do this or that in software X.
But I thought there's a lot professionals here and a good place to ask. If there's a better stack, let me know.

No, this is a good place to ask the "how". I, personally, just don't see how any of the irrelevant "social backstory" has anything to do with "how". But.. that's just my opinion. My opinion, is just that.. opinion. My opinion may not be the same opinion as others in this community. Not trying to dissuade you at all. Just voicing that the "back story" is overkill to me and has nothing to do with the "how" question. Linking to blogs/forums pertaining to the "legend" of the image merely feels like click baiting or SEO farming to me. Again, that doesn't mean I'm right.

Understood. It's not my page and not my reddit. If someone else has the same opinion I will happily remove it. Also if someone feels some in my post needs be removed, please feel free to remove it.

There's a really nice Photoshop tutorial on youtube which can get you part of the way there. https://youtu.be/CGdGqcAQdMU?si=m_EnJJ-mB9Ln018R

Here's an example I made using that tutorial, with me playing around with the settings - it can be used for colour or monochrome illustration effects.

I agree with @Scott if your intention is to ask about a workflow ask about a workflow.  All the excess text just makes it harder to be bothered even answering your question. SO are you looking to inverse the image transform, or are you interested in doing similar work.

I updated the text, hope it's better now.
